# Controlling projector with serial port

Tags: serial-port, port, projector

I've been trying to control Panasonic PT AE3000U through computer serial port for a last few days. Computer that I am using has serial port on its back, and I've confirmed that port functions at some level by connecting RXD and TXD with jump wire.

Technical information about projector (10Mb): http://www.projectorcentral.com/pdf/projector_manual_4506.pdf

Section that tells about serial communications starts from page 51.

According to manual and that what I've read from online, start-up command in hex should be 02 50 4f 4e 03, but I haven't been able to get it work with that.

Variations of that command I've tried to send with RealTerm and Termite:

```
02 50 4f 4e 03
02504f4e03
0x02 0x50 0x4f 0x4e 0x03
0x020x500x4f0x4e0x03
And other similar combinations and formats
```

I assume that command on third row should be the right one, because if I send that as numbers with Realterm, and connect RDX and TXD together similarly as I did before, I get this on screen (display settings are "display as ascii").

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rQT9.png

But when I connect cable to the projector and repeat the process, nothing happens. Baudrate is set at 9600, which should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess it somehow solved itself. I decided to restart my computer and projector. "Just in case there would be something left from all of mine failed attempts"

And it started to work, I sent line 0x02 0x50 0x4f 0x4e 0x03 with Realterm as numbers only. 
My settings were:

- Baudrate 9600
- Parity: None
- Data bits: 8
- Stop bits: 1